# Restangular: save vs. create

Tags: angularjs, restangular

According to the docs, `Restangular` method `save()` does `POST` or `PUT` depending on the need. However, the docs also say `save()` only works on elements, so how can you call `save()` for a new element that you are creating?

My code currently does two different Restangular calls depending on whether I'm creating or updating:

For create, it's `Restangular.all('foo').post($scope.fooData)`

For update it's

```
Restangular.one('foo', id).get().then(function (response) {
    $scope.fooData = response;
});
...
$scope.fooData.save()
```

Am I missing something? I think Restangular wants you to call `save` for either case, but I don't see how since in one case I need to `POST` to a collection (new element) and in another `PUT` on an existing element.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29305772/control-when-put-vs-post-is-called-with-restangular-save-method

Comment: I saw this, it doesn't show me code that replaces my code in the create case above.

Answer (score 1):

About `post()` , it's creator said once (*[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302395/restangular-post-always-empty#answer-17304522)*) :

> Posts should be done to collections, not to elements. So, if you want
>   to add a user to the building, you should do something like:
>
> ```
> Restangular.one("building", 5).post('users', user).then(function(postedUser) {
>     console.log("Success");
> })
> ```

Now the `save()` method is meant to decide if using the PUT or POST request. But according to its creator in [this github issue](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/1095#issuecomment-89348185) it will only work if you create your collection within `one` :

```
var user = Restangular.one('users');
user.name = 'gonto';
user.save() // Does POST
```

And that's what make it different from using `post()`. `save()` won't work with non restangularized objects and can't be called on a service created by `Restangular.service()`.

If you are using `one()` to retrieve an instance from your collection then you may let `save()` decide whenever the element is going to be *created* or *updated*. If not then you will have to implement `put`, `patch` or `post` by yourself. So your code may work this way :

```
Restangular.all('foo').post($scope.fooData)
```

But it will simply not if calling `save()` within `Restangular.all()` function.

As a different example, when working with nested models. I usually return the collection in an instance called `empty` to avoid confusion like so :

```
app.service('Foo', ['Restangular', function(Restangular) {
    ...
    return{
        ...
        empty: (function() {
            return Restangular.service('foos');
        }),
    };
}
```

Then this is how I create new elements inside controller :

```
$scope.foo= Foo.empty();

$scope.addFoo=function($foo){
    $scope.foo.post($foo).then(function(data) {
        ...
   });
}
```

And it works just fine with my API routing structure without using `save()` function.

- *Note: Talk & arguments before adding the `save()` method to **Restangular** started [here](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/584).*